# the correct use of does not equal in C?

Tags: c

I have this bit of code where I need to enter specific course CRN numbers, but if I enter anything but that number I want it to give me an error saying that isnt a possible answer choice. I thought this was how the != worked but when I type in the right answers I think get the "Sorry that is not an option"

```
if(amount == 1){
    printf("Enter the course number:\n");
    scanf("%f", &course);
        if(course != 4587){
            printf("Sorry invalid entry!\n");
        }
        else if(course != 4599){
            printf("Sorry invalid entry!\n");
        }
        else if(course != 8997){
            printf("Sorry invalid entry!\n");
        }
        else if(course != 9696){
            printf("Sorry invalid entry!\n");
        }
        else{
           switch(course)
                    {
                    case '4587':
                credit1 = 4;
                break;
                    case '4599':
                credit2 = 3;
                break;
                    case '8997':
                credit3 = 1;
                break;
                    case '9696':
                credit4 = 3;
                break;
                    }
        }

}
```

Comment: If it is not any of the correct answers, you will get an error. This has nothing to do with C, as your code is flawed

Comment: where is the definition of the "course" variable?

Comment: but that was the point, if I put anything that isnt the correct one I want it to give me an error, if I put the correct one I want it to run the switch and assign the value. sorry im very new to this

Comment: use fgets to read from keyboard instead, it will save you a lot of trouble as in `char buffer[128]; if (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin) != NULL) { ...`

Comment: I have int course right above it

Comment: The `case`-s for `switch(course)` must be without quotes: `case 4587:`

Comment: You read an int with `%d`, not `%f`. And the quotes in `case '4587'` are wrong as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not do what you think. Your else is only if the value `==` so checking against any other values does not make sense

```
       switch(course)
       {
         case 4587:
            credit1 = 4;
            break;
        case 4599:
            credit2 = 3;
            break;
        case 8997:
            credit3 = 1;
            break;
        case 9696:
            credit4 = 3;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Sorry invalid entry!\n");                
            break;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are doing the following:

If course isn't 4587, print an error.
If it is 4587, check if it is also 4599. If it isn't, print an error... and so on.

As you see, even If the first case is met, it's impossible for it to meet all cases as an integer can only have one value.

Try doing something like this:

```
if(course == 4587){
    credit1 = 4;
} else if(course == 4599){
    credit2 = 3;
} else if(course == 8997){
    credit3 = 1;
} else if(course == 9696){
    credit4 = 3;
} else {
    printf("Sorry invalid entry!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When passing `%f` to scanf, it will return a `float` type, which stands for a fraction. From the man page for scanf:

> f
>
> Matches an optionally signed floating-point number; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to float.

Later on, when it is being compared to a number of integer type, it fails.
The variable `course` should probably be declared as `int`.

Later on, in the switch case you use strings instead of integers.
The cases such as `case '4587':` should be `case 4587:` instead, and it will work.